# Undefined reference to local variable

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have the C++ factory class, which should be used in python script:

```
class CCommandFactory {
    private:
        typedef std::map<std::string, IAbstractCommandCreator*>::iterator factory_iter;
        static std::map<std::string, IAbstractCommandCreator*> m_factory;
    public:
        template<class T>
        static void add(const std::string& id) {
            factory_iter it = m_factory.find(id);
            if (it == m_factory.end()) {
                m_factory[id] = new CCommandCreator<T>();
            }
        }
        static ICommand* create(const std::string& id, boost::python::list args) {
            factory_iter it = m_factory.find(id);
            if (it != m_factory.end()) {
                std::list<std::string> arguments;
                for (int i = 0; i < len(args); ++i) {
                    arguments.push_back(boost::python::extract<std::string>(args[i]));
                }
                return it->second->create(arguments);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        ~CCommandFactory() {
            for (factory_iter it = m_factory.begin(); it != m_factory.end(); ++it) {
                if (it->second) {
                    delete it->second;
                }
            }
        }
};
```

Here it's the wrapper:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libfrtpsrv)
{
    class_<CCommandFactory, boost::noncopyable>("CCommandFactory", no_init)
        .def("create_command", &CCommandFactory::create, args("cmd_id", "args"), return_value_policy<manage_new_object>())
        .staticmethod("create_command")
    ;
}
```

The code looks correct for me, however the execution of the python script fails at the very beginning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File example.py, line 1, in <module>
    import wrapper
  File .../wrapper.py, line 4, in <module>
    from libfrtpsrv import *
ImportError: .../daemon/libfrtpsrv.so: undefined symbol: _ZN15CCommandFactory9m_factoryE
```

I have no idea how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see which symbol is failing with this command:

```
$ c++filt <<< _ZN15CCommandFactory9m_factoryE
CCommandFactory::m_factory
```

Static member variables of a class have to be defined somewhere, the declaration inside the class is just that, a declaration, but not a definition.

The solution is to add the definition of `m_factory` somewhere at namespace scope in a CPP file (not the header file or you will get duplicated symbols):

```
std::map<std::string, IAbstractCommandCreator*> CCommandFactory::m_factory;
```